# -2147483648 value in integer type column despite entry mask

Tags: sql-server, constraint, data-integrity

I have a desktop application with a textbox field that is a *[RadMaskedNumericInput](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/silverlight/controls/radmaskedinput/features/maskedinput-controls/numeric)* with `#6` masked value, meaning it can only have 6 digits. I store it in a database column of `int` type.

When I examine the database, some values in the column are -2147483648.

I have tried to enter many values, but I am unable to reproduce this scenario. I can only enter 6 digits in this screen. I tried the maximum, 999999, but it remains the same.

I am only getting the textbox value, converting it to `int`, and then inserting it into the database through a stored procedure.

```cs
int value = (int)txtPrice.value;
```

I have tried to enter negative values as well as trying to add letters, but
due to the mask, it is not allowing me to add any value other than integer.

According to my understanding and knowledge, it's only the desktop app that can insert or update this column's value.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening? How can I prevent it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't randomly set integers to -2147483648.

In any event it is clear that you have a constraint that should be being checked, negative prices are not good.

First clean up the rows with invalid values then you can add a check constraint

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable 
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_CheckPriceInRange CHECK(Price BETWEEN 0 AND 999999);
```

Now any attempt to set it to an invalid value will fail with an error.

You can of course do similar in your stored procedure

```
IF @Price NOT BETWEEN 0 AND 999999
    BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Invalid Price %d',16,1,@Price);
    RETURN;
    END
```

But you should still keep the check constraint as a last line of defence so however the invalid value appears it is stopped.